# Find Value from certain class (HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tampermonkey

I am looking to script a site that has a set of changing values. I am trying to figure out how to call the text value inside of only one of these entries at a time.

Any one of these can look like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, game) in crash.games.slice().reverse()" class="" style="">
<td ng-if="::game.crash > 199" class="crashHighResult">RANDOM NUMBER THAT I WANT TO SEE</td>
```

`tr` is the parent of `td` and the text value inside of `td` is what I'm trying to see

The only problem I'm experiencing is that there are as many as 20 entries stored during this time and they can all have seemingly the same classes and parents as every other one, the only difference being the random number value...

I am thinking that If I can pull them all at the same time and then maybe create an array with those values I might be able to do what I need to do but I'm a bit stumped.

I am very new to javascript and jquery and this is a learning experience for me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you are using jquery: `$('.classname')` can be used to select all elements with that class.

Comment: So, are you trying to create an array of the `td`s?

Comment: Do you only want the value of one specific td, or do you want to do something with each individual td's number?

Comment: @Confuzing What I want to do is ideally find the most recent td value that was created, but if I were to build an array with the most recent [0] and oldest [19] that would work well too. I just need to be able to find each individual value of each individual td

Comment: @Andy feel free to see my most recent comment thanks again

Comment: Recent isn't really descriptive without knowing how these td's are being inserted. Are you creating a new row and appending it to the end of a table?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use `document.querySelectorAll` if you want to understand some native JS techniques. There are a couple of other ways of getting the elements you want (`getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagName`) but they don't play nearly as well with `forEach` as does the former.

So, to grab the elements:

```
let cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');
```

And to loop over that nodelist:

```
cells.forEach(function (cell) {
  console.log(cell.textContent);
});
```

At the moment the code just logs the text content (your random number) to the console, but you can get a feel for what you can now do with that data.

For example, to get the last (most recent?) random number (the last cell in the nodelist) you would use:

```
let rnd = cells[cells.length - 1].textContent;
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Ah yes, you introduced me to a couple more functions I will probably need. Thank you very much. The most recent gets added to the table at the top not the bottom interestingly enough, but thanks a ton!

Comment: another quick question... i used some code to find the length of one table (less than 2) with  console.log(document.querySelectorAll('td.crashLowResult').length); however using the .textContent with that gives me an undefined in console and using an array attachment to the class gives me an error

Comment: Remember that `querySelectorAll` returns an array-like nodelist so you'll need to do something like `document.querySelectorAll('td.crashLowResult')[0].textContent` to get the content of the first cell, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to select the first `tr td` in the table to get the value, using jQuery you can select all `tr td` elements and then specify the first one.

`$("tr td").first().text();`

This selector finds all `tr td` elements as it traverses the dom, so it will find the top row in the table first. The `first()` function returns a jquery object of the first element found. The `text()` gets whatever text is inside the `td` tags, basically the same as the js `innertext` or `textcontent`.

If you want to do processing with all the values you can use the jquery selector `each()` function.

`$("tr td").each(function (index , element) {console.log($(element).text())})`

This loops through all the elements and prints their values to the console, but you could modify the function to sum the values, put them in an array, or whatever.

Comment: Thank you very much. On a side note, is there a jquery function to pull from any other set location other than first and last? Like 2nd, 3rd, 4th and so on?

Comment: quick googling has let me use the .eq() function and now I'm all set! I think I can finally complete my script! Thank all for your help!